# Flask application with Azure Blob Storage linkage

Tags: python, flask, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to select files/blob from an Azure container using a flask application for further usage in the application just like request.files.getlist('files') function help in selecting files from the local directory or folder?

What I have read through is to access blobs from python we need SAS tokens to access them. But these tokens are quite sensitive. I don't want to expose them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You python code runs on server side and is not going to be sent to the client so your access tokens should not be exposed.

Another way of doing it would be to generate a temporary SAS policy everytime an user logs in.

If the files are not sensitive (ie images for your site) you can have a storage account with anonymous access too.